# Content of wchar is deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, wchar-t

I have this code:

```
JSONObject object;
if (value->IsObject())
{
    object = value->AsObject();
    const wchar_t *tmp = from_string(entity_id);
    std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;
    std::wcout.flush();
    if (object.find(tmp) != object.end())
    {
        std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;
        std::wcout.flush();
        initFromJSON(object[tmp]->AsObject());
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Problem here is that after inner if statement, the content of a tmp is empty. Before that it's not.
When I try debuggin, it's everything ok, the content is not deleted. But when I run program, content is deleted. Any idea why?

Method `from_string(entity_id)` only convert from string to wchar like this:

```
std::wstring result;
for (int i = 0; i<content.length(); i++)
    result += wchar_t(content[i]);
return result.c_str();
```

Methods `JSONObject::find(...)` and `JSONObject::end()` are this:

```
iterator find(const key_type& __k)             {return __tree_.find(__k);}
iterator end() _NOEXCEPT {return __tree_.end();}
```

I don't believe that is problem in find(...) or in end(). I'm guessing that problem is somewhere else but I cannot locate it. Because the content of wchar is empty after the if statement I cannot say

```
initFromJSON(object[tmp]->AsObject());
```

because `object[tmp]` doesn't exist.

Any advice what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside Im pretty sure you dont need to call std::wcout.flush as you used std::endl which flushes the buffer for that stream.

Comment: Check flush as suggested by sam redway

Comment: even if I delete `std::wcout.flush` the error stil occurs

Comment: Your `from_string` function destroys the `std::wstring` when leaving the scope, so the pointer from `c_str` isn't valid anymore.

Comment: @Youka, but why then first std::wcout prints the correct content of variable tmp

Comment: And just for the record: this works on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 but not on OS X. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @golobich `And just for the record: this works on Ubuntu 1`  By pure luck.  You are returning a pointer to a local variable, thus you have invoked *undefined behavior* in the `from_string` function.  Why do you need `tmp` anyway?  There is no need for it from what I see.  The `from_string` should just return a `std::wstring` proper, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `from_string` function returns a pointer to a local entity, namely the return value of `std::wstring::c_str()`.  Thus you've introduced undefined behavior.

I see no reason at all for the `tmp` variable being a pointer. You should be able to do something like this instead:

```
std::wstring from_entity(...)
{
    std::wstring result;
    for (int i = 0; i<content.length(); i++)
        result += wchar_t(content[i]);
    return result;
}
```

And then this:

```
JSONObject object;
if (value->IsObject())
{
    object = value->AsObject();
    std::wstring tmp = from_string(entity_id);
    std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;
    std::wcout.flush();
    if (object.find(tmp.c_str()) != object.end())
    {
        std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;
        std::wcout.flush();
        initFromJSON(object[tmp.c_str()]->AsObject());
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that a `std::wstring` is returned, not a pointer.  Then within the function itself, you use `c_str()` if you need to pass a `const wchar_t*`.